# angular material 2 MdDialog hasBackdrop doesn't work with child popup

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have a parent component and a button. Button click opens a popup dialog with hasBackdrop:false so when the user clicks outside of the modal, the modal still stays open.
And inside this popup, I also have another button and clicking this button opens another modal with hasBackdrop:false property. And both works fine.
But when I click the second button it closes the first modal.

Sample screenshots: [image]

When I click Add Customer button, I am opening New Customer popup.
And when I click Save button if the form is not valid I open another modal but the first modal is closing.

[image]

and this is the code:

```
  openAddCustomerDialog() {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddCustomerComponent,
      {
      height: '600px',
      width: '600px',
      hasBackdrop:false
      }
    );

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log("selected in msgbox" + result);
    });
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

I have also tried with only one modal popup and I just gave an alert on Cancel button click and it still closes the modal.

```
<button md-dialog-close="Cancel" class="btn btn-warning btn-md" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>

  cancel()
  {
    alert('test');
    return true; // prevent any event bubbling
  }
```

This might be an MdDialog bug.

**UPDATE 2:** Full version of the HTML code

```
<span *ngIf="showLoader" class="loading">loading...</span>
<div>
  <h1 md-dialog-title>New Customer</h1>
  <div md-dialog-content>
    <form [formGroup]="AddCustomerForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="createCustomer(AddCustomerForm)">
      <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>
        <br/>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Firstname" class="col-lg-3 control-label">First Name</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
              <input id="Firstname" name="Firstname" formControlName="Firstname" required type="text" class="validate filter-input form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Lastname" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Last Name</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
              <input id="Lastname" name="Lastname" formControlName="Lastname" required type="text" class="validate filter-input form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Email" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
              <input mdInput formControlName="Email" email
              class="validate filter-input form-control">
            </div>
          </div>          
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Username" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Username</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
              <input id="Username" name="Username" formControlName="Username" required type="text" class="validate filter-input form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Password" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
              <input id="Password" name="Password" formControlName="Password" required type="text" class="validate filter-input form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Address" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Address</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
              <input id="Address" name="Address" formControlName="Address" required type="text" class="validate filter-input form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Postcode" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Postcode</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
              <input id="Postcode" name="Postcode" formControlName="Postcode" required type="text" class="validate filter-input form-control">
            </div>
          </div>          
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="City" class="col-lg-3 control-label">City</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
              <input id="City" name="City" formControlName="City" required type="text" class="validate filter-input form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Picture" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Picture</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
              <input type="file" (change)="uploadFileChange($event)" placeholder="Upload file" 
              id="Picture" name="Picture" formControlName="Picture"
              class="validate filter-input form-control"
              accept=".gif,.png,.jpg,.jpeg">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Country" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Country</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
              <select id="Country" name="Country" formControlName="Country" required class="validate filter-input form-control">
                  <option *ngFor="let country of countries" value= {{country.CountryID}}>
                      {{country.CountryName}}
                  </option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div md-dialog-actions align="center">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <br/>
            <button md-dialog-close="Save" type="button" (click)="createCustomer(AddCustomerForm)" class="btn btn-success btn-md">Save</button>
            <button md-dialog-close="Cancel" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-md" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is generally not recommended to have a layer of modals like that

Comment: Try setting `type="button"` on your "OK" button. I wonder if the top modal is accidentally submitting the first modal's form

Comment: thanks for this but it is still same, the buttons are not inside the form btw